# Automate Setting Jenkins Credentials and Global Variables

Tags: jenkins, automation, configuration, devops, jenkins-cli

I have Terraform+Ansible script that automates the deployment of a Jenkins server. However, I'd also like to pre-load that server with "Global" environment variables (Found in "Manage Jenkins" > "Configure System" > "Global Properties" > "Environment Variables"). I'm also looking to automatically set a few Jenkins credentials (found in "Manage Jenkins" > "Manage Credentials").

From what I understand, the credentials are stored encrypted in a file called `/var/lib/jenkins/credentials.xml`. And the global properties might be stored in `config.xml` in the same Jenkins directory, though the variables don't look very structured. I might be able to parse out the `config.xml` and add some values. But I'm wondering how I can create an encrypted secret that can be added to the `credentials.xml`.

Are there any tools or strategies for automating the creation of secrets and environment variables in Jenkins? I'm hoping that there's a better way to automate this other than parsing the xml documents. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be manually altering these files. You can use one of the following options to automate Credential and Global variable creation.

1. [Jenkins API.](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/)
2. [Jenkins CLI.](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/)
3. [Python-jenkinsapi](https://pypi.org/project/api4jenkins/). (Python wrapper for Jenkins API)

#### How to use Jenkins API to create credentials

Following commands need curl and jq. Execute in the same session.

```
# Change the following appropriately
JENKINS_URL="http://localhost:8080"
JENKINS_USER=admin
JENKINS_USER_PASS=admin
```

**Get the Crumb**

```bash
JENKINS_CRUMB=$(curl -u "$JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_USER_PASS" -s --cookie-jar /tmp/cookies $JENKINS_URL'/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
```

**Get the Access token**

```bash
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -u "$JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_USER_PASS" -H $JENKINS_CRUMB -s \
                    --cookie /tmp/cookies $JENKINS_URL'/me/descriptorByName/jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty/generateNewToken' \
                    --data 'newTokenName=GlobalToken' | jq -r '.data.tokenValue')
```

**Create Credentials**

```bash
curl -u $JENKINS_USER:$ACCESS_TOKEN \
    -H $JENKINS_CRUMB \
    -H 'content-type:application/xml' \
    "$JENKINS_URL/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials" \
    -d '<com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
          <id>TestCredentials</id>
          <description>This is sample</description>
          <username>admin2</username>
          <password>admin2</password>
        </com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>'
```

**Note:** *The credential create URL format is `/credentials/store/CREDENTIALS_STORE_NAME/domain/DOMAIN_NAME/` Change this appropriately if you want to create the Credential in a custom location. The easiest way to get this URL is by navigating to a existing credential from the UI and copying the URL.*
[image]

#### How to create Credentials from Jenkins CLI

```
# Change the following appropriately
JENKINS_URL="http://localhost:8080"
JENKINS_USER=admin
JENKINS_USER_PASS=admin
```

**Download the Jenkins CLI Jar**

```bash
wget $JENKINS_URL/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
```

Create a file named `cred.xml` with the following content.

```xml
<com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
  <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
  <id>PassID</id> 
  <username>Username</username>
  <password>password</password>
  <description>Description</description>
</com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
```

**Create credentials**

```bash
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s  $JENKINS_URL -auth $JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_USER_PASS create-credentials-by-xml system::system::jenkins _  < cred.xml
```

#### How to create credentials with Jenkins Python API

Following is a simple sample to create Global credentials using Jenkins Python API.

```py
from api4jenkins import Jenkins

j = Jenkins('http://localhost:8080', auth=('admin', 'admin'))

xmlPayload = '''<com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
  <id>user-id</id>
  <username>user</username>
  <password>upassword</password>
  <description>user id for testing</description>
</com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>'''

j.credentials.create(xmlPayload)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing those resources. I've used the python-jenkinsapi client a little bit in the past, but I can't seem to find how to get it to set secrets and configurations. It looks like it's more for running jobs and checking job status. Maybe I'm misunderstanding its use a bit. The Jenkins API documentation doesn't mention configuring Jenkins itself either; it talks about retrieving info from jenkins, triggering builds, and creating jobs.

Comment: @JoeJ I updated the answer to add samples to all three methods above. Have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for those examples - that's really cool.